# Individual user to group members notification

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am making a chat app like whatsapp , I am able to send notification using volley, firebase cloud messaging for individual users. I am facing a problem in notification , like whatsapp my app also have groups. I like to send notification to all group members when a user put a message in a group. That part how to implement I dont know.  Please find my code below that I have used to send notification. Any body please help..

```
    void sendNotification(String name, String message, String token){
    try {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
        JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
        data.put("title", name);
        data.put("body", message);
        JSONObject notificationData =new JSONObject();
        notificationData.put("notification",data);
        notificationData.put("to",token);


        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(url, notificationData
                , new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this,"Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this,error.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }){
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

                HashMap<String,String> map =new HashMap<>();

                String key ="Key=mykey";
                map.put("Authorization",key);
                map.put("Content-Type","application/json");
                return map;
            }
        };

        queue.add(request);


    }catch (Exception ex){

    }

}
```

public class MyFirebaseService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    RemoteMessage.Notification notification=remoteMessage.getNotification();
    sendNotification(notification.getTitle(),notification.getBody());



}
```

/////////////////////FirebaseMessagingService class//////////////////
public class MyFirebaseService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    RemoteMessage.Notification notification=remoteMessage.getNotification();
    sendNotification(notification.getTitle(),notification.getBody());



}

private void sendNotification(String title,String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    String channelId = "1";
    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.send_message)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(messageBody)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                "Channel human readable title",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

}

Comment: You would have to loop over each user's token and send a notification in the same way that you are sending the single notification

Comment: @Hydra other looping is there is any other efficient way to do that , like I read some where we can make groups in firebase cloud message (FCM) ,